# SMS sending is auto-blocked, how to fix?

Tags: sms-blocking

To a specific number, when I try to send a SMS, it is automatically/instantly blocked and fails.

Once, by mistake, I blocked sending messages to that number, but even after unblocking, the messages are still being blocked as if that number is still blocked.

I have deleted all old messages to that number, and also deleted all data and cache of the Messages app.

[image]

I have also tried to block and unblock again.
I went to application settings for this app but all looks ok.

I can send SMS to other numbers, it shows a waiting spinning icon and sends properly. But for the problematic number, it fails instantly, as if it doesnt even try to send the SMS at all, is blocked locally, by the Messages app...

Galaxy J7 Marshmallow.

Comment: @beeshyams after reboot, on the 1st try, it will show the spinning wait icon for about 3s and fail. All subsequent retries will instantly fail. Could this mean it was ,in some way, configured remotely on the provider as a blocked number, and my phone just retrieves that cfg and insta-blocks on sunsequent tries?

Comment: Mmm.. if I could send sms thru other apps that would be a workaround! bbl

Comment: Worked! And I set the new app as default! Should have tried that 2 years ago  :/. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt find a fix the bundled messages app.
As workaround I just installed google's one and after 2 years I can send messages to the specific number again, thx!